# Search Picasaweb (Google+ photos) by Album name?

Tags: google-plus-photos

Google has been uploading all photos on my phone and desktop to Google+ photos. As a result I overwhelmed with photos. I'm trying to find some particular albums but can't find a way to search by the Album name.

Comment: Google+ Photos has been retired. Are you having the same issue in Google Photos?

Answer (score 1):

## Alternatives

### Use Picasa Web Albums

1. Go to http://picasaweb.google.com
2. Click on [Show all albums](https://picasaweb.google.com/home?showall=true)
3. Use the Find command of your browser.

### Use Google Photos

1. Go to http://photos.google.com
2. (Optional) Click on [Collections](https://photos.google.com/collections)
3. Look for the album:

   1. Type the name of the album in the search box, then on the suggested auto-complete terms, select the name of the album
      OR
   2. If you are in the Collections view, use the Find command of your browser.

### Use Google Drive

Google Drive will not show albums but by default will organize photos in folders by Year and Month.

1. Go to http://drive.google.com
2. If you didn't this before, Click on [Google Photos](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/photos) click in the button to add a Google Photos folder to "My Drive"
3. Go to My Drive > Google Photos

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 useful options to search by album name:

1. Type *album: "[album name]"*
2. Go to https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/ [your user id] /albums - that way you will be able to view all your albums. Notice that you can find  by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkPHxRDp9wY) (notice that now Google uses letters, not numbers. So you just need to use "+your-username" instead of the number string. Don't forget the + (plus) char.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself on Google+?
#1 doesn't work for me. (Windows 7 /Chrome)
#2 Isn't usable for the reasons I described above (I have 100's of albums b/c Google has been auto-uploading all sorts of stuff)

Comment: I have tried this. It worked for me, but I have "only" ~30 albums. You should do this from the search area after clicking on Photos on the left menu option. Try the browser's find function, as Mary answered below.

Comment: see my comment below:  I have 1100+ albums so the browser "find" doesn't work.  I also tried your suggestion and it didn't work. See my **screencast**:  http://screencast.com/t/tQhySG6ttPE   . Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have Picasa installed on your computer? Maybe that way you'll be able to get an easy access to all albums http://picasa.google.com Don't forget to turn on sync once running the software

Comment: PeterBen,  This question was about the *web* interface (Google+). However, I have tried searching with the Desktop interface but I am on a slightly older version of Picasa (3.9.0) and the search did not work there either.)

Answer (score -1):

In option 2, the next step after viewing your hundreds of albums is to use the Find feature in your browser to search for the album name that you want.

Comment: I have 1100 albums, so this doesn't work (google is only showing about 50 albums)